# Boolean logic exercise set

Tags: ruby

I'm faced with the following problem:

> Set each variable to true or false depending on what value you expect the expression to return no quotes around true and false.

The code looks like this:

```
# test_1 = 77 != 77
test_1 = is/true 77 != 77

# test_2 = -4 <= -4
test_2 = is/true -4 <= -4

# test_3 = true -44 < -33
test_3 = is/true -44 <-33

# test_4 = false100 == 1000
test_4 = is/true 100 <= 1000
```

I keep getting this syntax error:

```
unexpected integer expecting $end
```

I'm completely new to Ruby. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you really need is

```
test_1 = 77 != 77 # false
test_2 = -4 <= -4 # true 
test_3 = -44 <-33 # true
test_4 = 100 <= 1000 # true
```

the "is/true" after the = sing is giving you the error just remove that and it should work just fine

Comment: Thank you very much MZaragoza it is not saying syntax error now it says value for test_4 isnt correct and inside the terminal just says true

Comment: I just got it so happy for test 4 changed <= to == and it works now thank you soo much thanks for helping me

Comment: :) Glad that was able to help